# Delete requests remaining in the Queue after CancelAll

Tags: java, android, android-volley

In the code below after the CancelAll and Stop, the request that added afterwards in the queue, will be immediately execute after the start command.

How can i remove the last request/requests that was inserted in queue?

```
    final  RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    String url ="";

    // Request a string response from the provided URL.
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                    Log.d("response", response);
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.d("VolleyError", error.toString());
        }
    });

    // Add the request to the RequestQueue.

    stringRequest.setTag("a");
    queue.cancelAll("a");
    queue.stop();
    queue.add(stringRequest);
    queue.start();
```

Comment: what exactly you want to do? when you want to cancel requests?

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh Ι cancel my requests when an error is thrown. But this error can come from different threads. So many requests may be added to the queue after the error and i want to delete them because they are invalid.

Answer (score 1):

As you `queue` reference is a local variable so you need to move it outside and since you are using it in activity so declare it like

```
private RequestQueue queue;

..oncreate(..){
    //... code
    queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
}
```

and create a separate method to cancel all requests as

```
void cancelAllQueuedRequests(){
    queue.cancelAll("a");
    queue.stop();
    queue.start();
}
```

call `cancelAllQueuedRequests` wherever you want and add requests like this

```
String url ="some url";

// Request a string response from the provided URL.
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
        new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {

                Log.d("response", response);
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        Log.d("VolleyError", error.toString());
        cancelAllQueuedRequests();
    }
});

// Add the request to the RequestQueue.

stringRequest.setTag("a");
queue.add(stringRequest);
//queue.start(); no need
```

Comment: As i said i have threads. The moment queue.stop() is executed, a thread might add a new request in queue. The next time the queue is executed, the "invalid ones" requests are going to be executed....and i dont want that. I want to clean the queue first.

Comment: volley add and cancelAll are both synchronized so at a time either requests can be added or cancelled

Comment: If you stop the queue (synchronized ) and then an other thread adds a request, the next time the queue starts, the last request gonna be executed, and i dont want that ,synchronized or not.

Comment: how you gonna decide to stop adding request from some thread, after error treads still can add new requests so how you can differentiate requests related to error when they are made after errors? anything?